# Django - Filter based on number of times a field comes up

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model that tracks the number of impressions for ads.

```
class Impression(models.Model):
    ad = models.ForeignKey(Ad, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_ip = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    clicked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to find all the `user_ip` that has more than 1000 impressions.  In other words, if a `user_ip` comes up in more than 1000 instances of `Impression`. How can I do that?  I wrote a function for this but it is very inefficient and slow because it loops over every impression.

```
def check_ip():
    for i in Impression.objects.all():
        if Impression.objects.filter(user_ip=i.user_ip).count() > 1000:
            print(i.user_ip)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this in one query with aggregation.. it is possible to filter on aggregate values (like `Count()`) as follows:

```
from django.db.models import Count

for ip in Impression.objects.values('user_ip').annotate(ipcount=Count('user_ip')).filter(ipcount__gt=1000):
    # do something
```

Comment: Great!  I'll fix the import.

Comment: This should work on any of Django's DB backends, not just Postgres. It's not using DISTINCT ON.

Comment: You are right I am mixing up passing fields to values() with passing fields to distinct()...

Answer (score 0):

Django querysets have an `annotate()` method which supports what you're trying to do.

```
 from django.db.models import Count

 Impression.objects.values('user_ip')\
     .annotate(ip_count=Count('user_ip'))\
     .filter(ip_count__gt=1000)
```

This will give you a queryset which returns dictionaries with 'user_ip' and 'ip_count' keys when used as an iterable.

To understand what's happening here you should look at Django's aggregation guide: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/ (in particular [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#values) which explains how `annotate` interacts with `values`)

The SQL generated is something like:

```
SELECT "impression"."user_ip", COUNT("impression"."user_ip") AS "ip_count"
FROM "impression"
GROUP BY "impression"."ip"
HAVING COUNT("impression"."ip") > 1000;
```